# Unhandled rejection Error: Invalid path

Tags: javascript, reactjs

When I `npm run dev` a react project, it encounters an error like this:

```
Unhandled rejection Error: Invalid path './dist/'
```

Someone told me I should try an absolute path, but the error lies there again.

```
Unhandled rejection Error: Invalid path '／path／to/dist/'
```

I am confused~  anybody encountered this problem？

```
const output = {
  path: './dist/',
  filename: 'bundle.js',
  publicPath: '../'
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the leading `./` in your path might be the problem. As a work-around, you can try something like this:

```
path: require("path").resolve("./dist")
```

Also, from the error message, I think the absolute path you're using isn't working because it also has a leading `.`